# void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object referenc

Tags: java, android, using

I have added one button "btn". I have set onclicklistener, inside the button "btn" I have added another button "btnYes" to show display custom dialog when I add these "btnYes" apps get crash.

When I remove the "btnyes" button app is working. 
Can we add onclicklistener for two button inside one button for different work?

**Java Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn, btnYes, btnNo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.click);
        btnYes = findViewById(R.id.yes);
        btnNo = findViewById(R.id.no);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

                View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialogbox, null);
                dialogBox.setView(myView);
                final AlertDialog mybuilder = dialogBox.create();
                mybuilder.setCancelable(false);
              btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      mybuilder.dismiss();

                  }
              });


            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.customdialog.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)

Comment: Are your `btnYes` and `btnNo` buttons on your main activity or on the dialog? If they are on the dialog, you shouldn't initialize them using the `MainActivity`'s `findViewById` method as they do not exist there and thus the references will be `null`. Rather, call the `findViewById` on the `AlertDialog`'s `View` object, after inflating it inside the outer listener.

Answer (score 2):

If `btnYes` and `btnNo` are on the dialog, then you should `initialize` these buttons using the `AlertDialog's` View `object`.

You have to modify your code like following.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn, btnYes, btnNo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.click);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

                View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialogbox, null);

                // these button should be initialize here.
                 btnYes = myView.findViewById(R.id.yes);
                 btnNo = myView.findViewById(R.id.no);

                dialogBox.setView(myView);
                final AlertDialog mybuilder = dialogBox.create();
                mybuilder.setCancelable(false);
              btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      mybuilder.dismiss();

                  }
              });


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display Dialog with choices yes or no, use this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        // action for yes

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        // action for no

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

But, if you want to use a custom dialog layout, you should do it like this.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_HERE);
        Button btnyes= dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnyes);

btnyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
```